# Difficulty generating C# classes from complex XSD

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, jdf

I am trying to generate classes for JDF format, as available from [here](http://www.cip4.org/Schema/JDFSchema_1_4a_20091217.zip).
I have tried using the xsd.exe tool and the error/warning that pops up is:

"Schema validation warning: Type  is not declared, or is not a simple type."

And correct, the type is defined in an imported XSD file and is indeed a complex type.

When I open the XSD schema in Altova it all works like a charm, so there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the schema itself.

Comment: That schema is all wrong... it includes the same files from various places, hence all the 'already declared' warnings.

Comment: Thank you leppie, so would you suggest that I remove the includes?

Comment: That is a massive schema, I would not know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide all the referenced XSD files to XSD.exe:

```
xsd.exe schema1.xsd schema2.xsd schema3.xsd /c
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I have a different error:

Schema validation warning: The complexType 'http://www.CIP4.org/JDFSchema_1_1:Comment_Type' has already been declared. Line 65, position 4.